# How to validate json of specific class which contains attribute of unknown type

Tags: javascript, typescript, validation, javascript-objects, typescript-typings

I have a class which has an attribute of type unknown.

```
class A {
  known_attribue: 'string';
  unknown_attribute_name:unknown;
}
```

I need to validate a json and return values which are of type A.

for instance consider the following json

```
const x = {
  a : 'value1',
  c:[
     {
       known_attribue:'known_value1'
       unknown_attribute_name: {
         attr1 = 'attribute1_value1';
         attr2 = 'attribute2_value1';
       }
    }
  ],
  d: {
       known_attribue:'known_value2'
       unknown_attribute_name: {
         attr3 = 'attribute3_value1';
       }
    }
}
```

The result should be

```
[
{
       known_attribue:'known_value2'
       unknown_attribute_name: {
         attr3 = 'attribute3_value1';
       }
}, 
{
       known_attribue:'known_value1'
       unknown_attribute_name: {
         attr1 = 'attribute1_value1';
         attr2 = 'attribute2_value1';
       }
}
]
```

Sample JSON data

Could someone please help me with this? Have tried lots of approaches but failed to get the results. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Clarification: Is there a reason you’re using a `class` instead of an `interface` here? At runtime none of those are instances of `A`. Unless you want to see `new A` somewhere in the answer to this question, I’d suggest changing to `interface` to avoid the distraction.

Comment: (continued) Could you please [edit] that sample JSON so it's syntactically valid?  Right now it has typos in it.  Ideally any code posted should be a [mre] that demonstrates an issue without having unrelated problems.

Comment: (continued) Once you do that, please check if the code [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wExJZW) meets your needs.  If so I'll write up an answer (but please make the requested edits to the question first).  If not, please [edit] to clarify what you need.